# ActionBarSherlock not show all menuItem under android 2.x

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

I have some issue with ActionBarSherlock

On android 4 it's ok :
[image: On android 4 it's ok]

But on android 2.3 
[image]

One option is missing !!! And submenu was not show to show this option.

This is how i create the menu:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.add("Controls")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    menu.add("Theme")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    menu.add("Advanced")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    menu.add("Profils")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    menu.add("Save")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    return true;
}
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Which option is missing? If you mean 'Advanced' and 'Profils', note that on Android 2.x, you need to press the hardware Menu button to see the extra options

Comment: You're right!!!! This is what i miss ! Thanks a lot ! 
Do you know if there a way to have same as Android 4 on Android 2.x ? Because have to push menu button it's not cool.

Comment: Android 4.x auto detects whether hardware buttons are present or not and either shows the soft menu option or not. I don't know if you can force it to think there are no hardware keys. Note that the default behaviour is good for consistency for those who are used to having hardware keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On devices with a hardware Menu button, you need to press the hardware Menu button in order to view overflow options. The soft menu button is only available on devices without hardware buttons.